# Combine "WHERE" queries with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

In regular SQL I could write a query like

`select * from geocodes where NAME='somename' and STATE='somestate'`

But in LINQ I can't figure out how to do this. I'd like to write some combined queries for the following single queries that I'm doing with LINQ:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            switch (searchBy)
            {
                case "Name":
                    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.NAME.Contains(searchString));
                    break;
                case "Site":
                    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.CFN_SITE.Contains(searchString));
                    break;
                case "Address":
                    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.STREET1.Contains(searchString));
                    break;
                case "City":
                    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.CITY.Contains(searchString));
                    break;
                case "State":
                    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.STATE_CODE.Contains(searchString));
                    break;
                case "Acct":
                    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.AccountNumber.Contains(searchString));
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is `geocodes` an `IQueryable`? And what doesn't work with the code you show here?

Comment: Why don't you use `&&` in the condition? Are you trying to construct the `Where` conditions dynamically?

Comment: If you *remove* `switch` and use `if (shouldThisConditionBeUsed)` for each case you'll get a dynamically generated sequence of `Where(..).Where(..)` calls that are equivalent to `&&`

Comment: Removing the switch statement is an interesting proposition. I might try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `geocodes` is an `IQueryable<>` then you can leverage the deferred execution that comes with creating a queryable object. Your code might look something like this:

```
if(searchByName) //Some boolean value to indicate you are searching the name
{
    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.NAME.Contains(searchString));
}

if(searchBySite)
{
    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.CFN_SITE.Contains(searchString));
}

if(searchByAddress)
{
    geocodes = geocodes.Where(s => s.STREET1.Contains(searchString));
}

//etc...
```

Your query won't actually be sent to the database as you are purely building it up. Entity Framework will build the SQL it needs only when you materialise the data by enumerating the results (by calling `ToList()` or just looping over it)

Comment: Would this be similar to the comment indicating the use of "IF" statements to build a multi-faceted WHERE query? At what point does the query get executed then? Essentially, I could use this to build several filters at once into the logic?

Comment: Yes, this is the same as building up with `if` statements, and yes, this is a common pattern to build up EF queries.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `&&` logical AND operator:

```
geoCodes = geoCodes.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(someName) && s.State.Contains(someState));
```